# Parser CSV Php save Json

Tags: php, json, csv

The parser does not work on large CSV files. CSV file 70M
What could be the problem?

```
  function parses($f) {
    if (($f = fopen('84k.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
for ($json = array(); $row = fgetcsv($f, 2000);) {
             $json[] = array( 'model'=>$row[2], 'detal'=>$row[1],'dop' => array( 'nam'=>$row[0], 'sum'=>$row[4], 'img'=>'http://'.$row[5], 'info'=>$row[6]) );
}
            fclose($f);
            json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            file_put_contents('file/newsss1d.json', json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

        }
}
parses();
```

Comment: "Does not work". Please elaborate. What errors  / messages / whatever are you seeing?

Comment: Why does it not work? Any errors?

Comment: out of memory error no doubt

Comment: Verify that your php.ini file allows files of such size. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: HTTP ERROR 500 displays.

Comment: In the absence of the opportunity to increase memory. How can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try increasing your memory limit:

```
ini_set(’memory_limit’, ‘128M’);
```